# How do I remove/replace border pixels from my image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to Matlab and will need some help. I have a segmented image in which I would want to remove background (or black) pixels (with value == 1) from the image borders. I have been able to obtain an image mask of the border pixels that I do not want. The interior_blackPixels are useful but I want to get rid of the outer_blackPixels, however, I am not sure how to retrieve the final image without the black pixel borders using the mask (outer_blackPixels) that I have. The code so far is shown below:

```
img =   [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
         1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1
         1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1
         1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1
         1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1
         1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1
         1 3 3 1 1 1 3 1
         1 3 3 1 1 1 3 1
         1 3 3 3 3 3 3 1
         1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];

% Get the black pixels image array
blackPixels = (img == 1);

% Obtain the other pixels by negating the black pixels
otherPixels = ~blackPixels

% Get the border black pixels (or mask)
outer_blackPixels    = blackPixels & ~imclearborder(blackPixels)
interior_blackPixels = blackPixels & ~outer_blackPixels
```

Please note that I do not mind replacing the pixel values of the outer_blackPixels to ‘0’ as this will not affect my analysis. Hence, I would expect my final image to be something like this:

```
img =   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0
         0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0
         0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0
         0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0
         0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0
         0 3 3 1 1 1 3 0
         0 3 3 1 1 1 3 0
         0 3 3 3 3 3 3 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bwlabel` to differentiate between the 1's areas. Because this function treats only binary images, you can use `logical` to convert `img` to binary:

```
L=bwlabel(~logical(img-1),4)
```

And then just convert the borders to 0:

```
img(L==L(1))=0
```

`img` =

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     2     2     2     0
 0     0     0     2     2     2     2     0
 0     0     0     2     2     2     2     0
 0     0     2     2     2     2     2     0
 0     0     2     2     2     2     2     0
 0     3     3     1     1     1     3     0
 0     3     3     1     1     1     3     0
 0     3     3     3     3     3     3     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Image Processing Toolbox, I would suggest the [`imfill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) function:

```
img(~imfill(img ~= 1, 'holes')) = 0;
```

This first creates a mask for pixels in `img` that are not equal to one, fills any internal holes that contain ones using `imfill`, negates that to get a mask for the border ones, and indexes `img` with that mask, setting values to zero.

If you want to do something like this without using the Image Processing Toolbox, a solution of the type from [Adiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41216797/52738) using [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) is the way I would go.

Comment: Many thanks @ Adiel and gnovice both solutions work perfectly. Also, going forward from where my code stopped, i realized that all i needed to do was to include the line: img(outer_blackPixels) = 0 and that would have been enough. Nevertheless, i do appreciate your help.

Comment: Gnovice: i have always seen your comments and as such admired your intuition and finesse... what an honour to have you comment on my post. Special thanks to you!